# Is it possible to get a collection inside a document along with all the other doc data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Basically I have a doc that has an id, a name and a collection inside. When I do

```js
const {name, id} = doc.data()
```

I get the ID and name, however when I try to get the collection named items (by destructuring it like above) it returns undefined. How can I get this collection? Do I have to make another ref to the items collection and then get() or is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries in Firestore are shallow.  When you get a document snapshot, it doesn't contain any of the subcollections nested under that document.  If you want data from subcollections, you will have to query each subcollection individually by building a path to it:

```
firestore
    .collection("top-level-collection")
    .doc("doc-id")
    .collection("nested-subcollection")
    .get()
```

This will get you all the documents in the nested subcollection.  You must know its name in order to query it.

Comment: Alright! Thanks :D I was secretly hoping there was but I figured not :) Thank you for the answer!!